# When inserting multiple record into a SQL table it does not follow the order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, sql-insert

When using a single insert statement to add multiple records into a table as shown below, it does not follow the same order when selecting. I understand that it does not affect anything but may I know why is this the case?

```
CREATE TABLE [category]
(
    [category_id] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [category_name] varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

```
INSERT INTO [category] (category_name) 
VALUES ('Laptops and Accessories'),
       ('AI Development Kit'),
       ('Cameras and Lens');

SELECT * FROM [category]
```

Output:

[image]

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: "I'm using MS SQL but I can't add the tag" -- that's because it's actually called "SQL Server". But the SQL Server tag appears in the selection when typing "mssql".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select statement explicitly says: *"I do not care about the order!"* - it does so by omitting the `ORDER BY` clause.

If you say `SELECT * FROM [category] ORDER BY [category_id]` you will get an ordered result set along the lines of

```
1, 'Laptops and Accessories'
2, 'AI Development Kit'
3, 'Cameras and Lens'
```

Which is exatly the order you gave in your `INSERT` statement.

`SELECT`s in SQL without an `ORDER BY` clause are not only not expected to be in some order, they are also not expected to have the same order when called multiple times.